# Call to a member function getData() on a non-object in Magento Extension

Tags: php, magento

Hello Magento Experts,

I developed a `Magento Extension` which is working fine on `Version 1.6 and 1.7`, but when i installed it on `Version 1.5`, it is giving me an error :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getData() on a non-object in /home/broadcas/public_html/app/code/community/Gwb/Magecrmsync/controllers/Adminhtml/OrdersController.php on line 18
```

Below is my `OrderController.php` Code.

```
<?php
class Gwb_Magecrmsync_Adminhtml_OrdersController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
public function indexAction()
{
    $model = Mage::getModel('sales/order');

    $collection = $model->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('status', array("in" => array('complete','closed','pending','holded','payment_review','pending_payment','pending_paypal','processing')));

    $data = array();
    $orderArr = array();

    // getting order details

    $records = 0;
    foreach($collection as $order)
    {
        $data[$records]['order_data']['shipping_address'] = $order->getShippingAddress()->getData(); // get shipping details
        $data[$records]['order_data']['billing_address'] = $order->getBillingAddress()->getData(); // get billing details
        $data[$records]['order_data']['order_total'] = $order->getGrandTotal(); // get total amount
        $data[$records]['order_data']['shipping_amount'] = $order->getShippingAmount();
        $data[$records]['order_data']['order_details'] = $order->toArray();
        $records++;
    }

    // getting order details

}
}
```

Can anyone please guide me what am i doing wrong which doesn't work in `Version 1.5`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It's maybe because the `getBillingAddress()` or `getShippingAddress()` is currently returning a null, so you are trying to call a method `getData()` on something which is not an object. Try to add some debug to know what is `$order->getShippingAddress()` and `$order->getBillingAddress()` and if your order has such method.

Comment: @user1073122 , you are right. getShippingAddress() is returning null. So how can i find shipping address and billing address in version 1.5?

Comment: You should refer to your magento extension. I can't help you more at this point. Try to check what is the classname of your object $order and take a look at the class definition to know what method are available.

Comment: What's the code of the model on `getShippingAddress()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my answer. You should check `$order->getShippingAddress()` is object or not. because if product is virtual. The shipping address will be set.

```
class Gwb_Magecrmsync_Adminhtml_OrdersController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
public function indexAction()
{
    $model = Mage::getModel('sales/order');

    $collection = $model->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('status', array("in" => array('complete','closed','pending','holded','payment_review','pending_payment','pending_paypal','processing')));

    $data = array();
    $orderArr = array();
    // getting order details
    $records = 0;
    foreach($collection as $order)
    {

            if(is_object($order->getShippingAddress()))
            {    
                $data[$records]['order_data']['shipping_address'] = $order->getShippingAddress()->getData(); // get shipping details
            }    
            else
            {
                $data[$records]['order_data']['shipping_address'] = array(); // no shipping details
            }

            if(is_object($order->getBillingAddress()))
            {
                $data[$records]['order_data']['billing_address'] = $order->getBillingAddress()->getData(); // get billing details
            }
            else
            {
                $data[$records]['order_data']['billing_address'] = array(); // no billing details    
            }

            $data[$records]['order_data']['order_total'] = $order->getGrandTotal(); // get total amount
            $data[$records]['order_data']['shipping_amount'] = $order->getShippingAmount();
            $data[$records]['order_data']['order_details'] = $order->toArray();
              $records++;
    }

    // getting order details

}
}
```